Merge two Power BI reports into one report
Our team is parallelly working on two separate pages within a Power BI Report. Is there a way to merge these pages together? Additionally, we need to combine different bookmarks and report-level measures from both pages.
Currently I found one approach by creating PBIP file. And I was able to copy the pages from sections array of report.json file, However, I encountered challenges in locating and copying the measures and bookmarks from the configuration.
